# What is the current situation with as3/Flash/Flex and the RESTful web?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, rest

Searching for information about Flash/Flex + REST yields several many years old blog posts (from 2009, 2008 and even earlier) but no information about the current situation, especially related to Flash Player 11.

Also, many of the libraries that were apparently very popular at that time (as3httpclient, resthttpservice, etc) appear quite outdated and seemed to have died a quick and silent death (last commit over 2 years ago, proposed changes for a new version which was never released, etc).

Did something change with the current Flash Player regarding the RESTful abilities? Are there any still actively supported and maintained libraries available to handle REST calls if the FP still doesn't provide that functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not really anything special you need to do to connect to a RESTful API vs. any other web service, so once the basic steps were documented, there wasn't any need to talk about it further. From my experiences in using these services, they're basically just fromalized interfaces to CRUD.

I do feel that Flash has weaker capabilities in this area than Flex, which might be the gap these libraries once filled, but it's not difficult to write a minimal implementation that mimics what Flex does in Flash.

Comment: I'm especially concerned about/interested in all the stuff that appears to supposedly be broken in Flash Player for REST: very limited access to response headers, stripping of request headers on everything but POST, inability to perform native PUT and DELETE calls (requiring some hacks like X-HTTP-Method-Override), and so on and so forth. Is Flash still such a minefield with lots of things to keep in mind vs just using REST?